# Can you install a service through GPO?

Tags: windows, group-policy, service

I know it's possible to run and stop services that are already installed, but is it possible to install a brand new service with a given executable?

Comment: "...with a given executable" as in not an installer package but the application itself?

Comment: You can use SRVANY & INSTSRV Old but still working tutorial from Microsoft [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137890](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/137890)

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Depending on your AD environment, you can deploy lots of applications through GPO using SMS, which is now SCCM; or you can do it plainly (and painstakingly old-school using self-built packages).  It depends on if your infrastructure already supports deploying applications or if you need to build a Frankenstein solution.

Here's the MS article on how to do it with old-school GPO methods:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/816102

Note: you need to be careful about the GPO permissions to be able to deploy the applications properly.  In some cases, you'll need to apply the GPO security permissions to both computer and user groups.